# Why don't C++ error messages describe the actual problem in the code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Why do the Visual Studio error logs show the things caused by some error, rather than the error itself? I often find the error messages to be useless and meaningless.

When I make a mistake, like for example a circular dependency, it throws a bunch of errors like
`syntax error: missing ';'` instead of something like `circular dependency detected`.

When I forget to include some header and use it in my code, for example the `std::map`, it only says `'map' is not a member of 'std'`

It never shows you what's actually wrong, it only shows the symptoms. I know that sometimes you can clearly see what's wrong based only on that, but I don't want to spend time figuring out what's wrong. I just want to fix it as soon as possible.

Why can't it be like Python with Pycharm IDE which actually shows you the actual error?

Comment: You get used to it (at least to some degree). `'map' is not a member of 'std'` is easy to understand, IMO. But I agree that circular includes could use a warning.

Comment: C++ is not Python. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. When a program is ill-formed there are many high-level reasons for the error message. All the compiler can tell you is the low-level, technical reason why the code is ill-formed, and it's up to the programmer to figure out what the real reason is.

Comment: Understanding error messages comes with experience. One tip I will give you is to look at the error messages in the Output Tab instead of the Errors List. The output tab information is often more verbose and its always in the correct order which is important because a single error can cause many error reports.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on-topic.  If you are genuinely asking why your compiler is "unhelpful" and "meaningless",  those are feelings. They are a matter of opinion.

Comment: I don't agree with that the compiler tells you the symptoms, it tells you cold hartedly what it finds is wrong. And its not only about visual studio some compilers give you better messages in some cases and others in other case. You can experience this yourself on https://godbolt.org/ where you can compile code with different compilers (and versions of those compilers) to see what I mean.

Comment: I'm afraid next question will be « why doesn't the compiler do what I'm thinking about instead of doing what I told it to do ? »

Comment: Errors usually tells you what file, and line the error is on. Some errors are easy to understand, and some are not. I would say it's something that comes with the fact that the language is a lot more complex then for example python, and also the syntax is a lot more complex.

Comment: Comrade, you're missing out on the good old days of *syntax error*. That's it. That's all you got. *syntax error* Maybe you also got a line number, but that number was almost always wrong.

Comment: Why don’t you just try multiple different compilers and check which one reports errors in a way you find understandable? At least 3 more well-known compilers are readily available, either open-source or at least at no charge. Plus it is always good practice to make sure that your C++ projects build without warnings with more than one compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though this question might be considered out of topic, I'll attempt to give an answer to make it clear why one might find the experssed opinion (useless and meaningless) as "unfair".

Firstly this is not a Visual studio thing. If you've used other C++ compilers (gcc/clang/intel compiler) you'll notice the errors are pretty similar. Even though they might seem "useless", a little experience goes a long way. Not only are the errors precise, exact and reproducible, but they follow a standard specification and adhere to the formal description of the language.

Secondly we have to draw a line when comparing C++ to Python. **C++ is a compiled language** meaning that prior to creating an executable the entirety of your code must be written according to the language rules. This means that a runtime branch is checked even if it's not executed. **Python on the other hand is an interpreted language**. This means that it verifies code on the fly (having richer information on the execution context) so the following code will probably run fine:

```
def main():
    a = []
    a.append(1)
    print(a)
    # return 9'999 out of 10'000 times
    a.shoot_foot(2) # list object has no attribute 'shoot_foot'
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This comes with the price that an error (not even calling this a bug since it violates language rules) may remain hidden and manifest in production.

Thirdly **C++ is a strongly typed language**. This means that types are statically checked, at the price of requiring **you** to be correct about them. Unlike the **dynamically typed Python** the type of an object cannot be modified at runtime which means increased type safety at the price of "being careful" when programming. It's a JS vs TS kind of thing, and people get accustomed to different styles; for me the lack of type safety is the thing I miss the most when working with Python. This power comes at the price of some of the most intricate error messages when doing type checking.

Lastly C++ is actively evolving towards improving error messages, making them more informative and shorter. This is not an easy task but features like **concepts** allow programmers to be explicit on the restrictions they impose to the type sytem. Additionally defensive programming techniques like static assertions can introduce a "fail switch" that stops compilation early resulting in less errors and keeping only the information about the offensive code.